# Split number of hours between intervals and sum

Tags: java, date, intervals

I'm working with date intervals in Java, and I have a initial date (let`s say 04-04-2013 11:00:00), and a number of hours (for example, 12:00), and some intervals (like Sunday 09:00 - 18:00, Monday 10:00 - 13:00, 14:00 - 17:00) that can be speficied by the users, what means that it can be as many intervals as he wants, ir one or more days.

Now, what I need to do is to split that number of hours on these intervals, until it ends, and so add it on the initial date.

For examples:

04-04-2013, 12 hours to split, and the next day have a interval of 09:00 - 18:00 (9 hours), and the next one is 10:00 - 15:00 (5 hours). Is this case, 12 hours will be splited on 9 hours of day 5, and more 3 hours of day 6. So, the final date will be 04-06-2013 13:00 (since day 6 starts at 10:00, and I still need 3 hours...)

There is a easy way to do this? Any lib with these functions or something similar? Thanks

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: i did not get it :( ...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
Date[] intervalStart = <<specify all the starts of all the intervals>>;
Date[] intervalEnd = <<specify all the ends of all the intervals>>;

long totalTimeRemaining = <<hours>> * 60 * 60 *1000;  //milliseconds

for (int i=0; i<intervalStart .length; i++) {
    long intervalLen = intervalEnd[i].getTime()- intervalStart[i].getTime();
    if (intervalLen > totalTimeRemaining) {
        return new Date(intervalStart[i].getTime()+totalTimeRemaining);
    }
    totalTimeRemaining = totalTimeRemaining - intervalLen;
}
```

Walk through the different intervals, calculate the length of an interval, and subtract it from the total remaining time.  If the interval is longer than time remaining, just calculate the end time by adding the remaining amount to the start time of that interval.